# Spring Configuration for JMS (Websphere MQ - SSL, Tomcat, JNDI, Non IBM JRE)

Tags: spring, tomcat, jms, jndi, ibm-mq

**Background:**
I have a relatively old application that uses Websphere MQ for messaging. It runs on WAS (Websphere Application Server) and uses MDBs (Message Driven Beans). I was successfully able to replace all MDBs using [Spring Integration - JMS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html). My next step is try to see if I can port it out of WAS so that it can run on any other servlet container with a non-IBM JRE (I am trying: apache tomcat). Note that securing channels using SSL is a requirement. I prefer using JNDI.

**End Goal:** 
To decouple my application from the application server (WAS) and other infrastructure like messaging (MQ). But taking this out of WAS onto tomcat is the first step. Next comes the task of updating my messaging infrastructure with something more scalable. This allows me to update individual components of the infrastructure that my app relies on, one thing at a time (app server, messaging layer, datastore) without disrupting my application too much, as I go.

**Question:**
Now, my challenge is to define JNDI resources on tomcat that can access Websphere MQ. I have made some progress on this using non-SSL channels that I defined in the context.xml file like so:

```xml
<Resource
   name="jms/qcf_sandbox"
   auth="Container"
   type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
   factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
   description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
   HOST="localhost"
   PORT="1414"
   CHAN="CHANNEL_SANDBOX"
   TRAN="1"
   QMGR="QM_SANDBOX"/>
<Resource
   name="jms/SandboxQ"
   auth="Container"
   type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
   factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
   description="JMS Queue"
   QU="SANDBOX_Q"/>
```

My next step is to get this to work with SSL channels. I understand the part that involves setting up the keystores (kdb file and cert generation and exchanging), configuring the SSL channels on the QM etc. I have all that working already. How do I get tomcat to use my keystore, cipher suite etc? Pointers or a working example would be great!

Note: I am using Spring Integration 4.2, Websphere MQ v8, Tomcat v9, currently.

I must add that I did try everything without the JNDI first. So here's my spring jms non-ssl config without the JNDI, that works:

```xml
<bean id="mq-jms-cf-sandbox"
   class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
    <ref bean="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="mqQueueConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
   <property name="hostName" value="localhost" />
   <property name="port" value="1414" />
   <property name="queueManager" value="QM_SANDBOX" />
   <property name="transportType" value="1" />
   <property name="channel" value="CHANNEL_SANDBOX" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="jms-destination-sandbox" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
   <constructor-arg value="SANDBOX_Q" />
    <property name="baseQueueManagerName">
    <value>QM_SANDBOX</value>
    </property>
    <property name="baseQueueName">
    <value>SANDBOX_Q</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I finally figured out how to pull this off... here's a brief description of the steps. If you need more details let me know.

**Pre-reqs**: 
Websphere MQ Server installed (at least v 8.0.0.2)
Configure the QM, SSL and non-SSL channels, create Qs and all that good stuff you need.
Needless to say, you need the Websphere MQ jars. Be mindful of any licensing restrictions.

**Step 1**: Get the direct connection working with no SSL, no JNDI. You will need to use these beans to configure your spring based JMS listeners and JMS Templates etc.

```
<bean id="mq-jms-cf-sandbox"
   class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
    <ref bean="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="mqQueueConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
   <property name="hostName" value="localhost" />
   <property name="port" value="1414" />
   <property name="queueManager" value="QM_SANDBOX" />
   <property name="transportType" value="1" />
   <property name="channel" value="NON_SSL_CHANNEL" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="jms-destination-sandbox" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
   <constructor-arg value="SANDBOX_Q" />
    <property name="baseQueueManagerName">
    <value>QM_SANDBOX</value>
    </property>
    <property name="baseQueueName">
    <value>SANDBOX_Q</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Step 2**: Get the direct connection working with SSL, no JNDI. I found setting this up a little tricky.

**2a**. Since I was using a non-IBM JRE, I had to make sure the cipher specs & cipher suites needed to be configured according to the mappings specified here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840

This obviously means that we at least have to have our Websphere MQ upgraded to 8.0.0.2. In my case I used ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 on the SSL channel and configured the jms beans within application to use TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, like so:

```
<bean id="mq-jms-cf-sandbox"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <ref bean="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="mqQueueConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
  <property name="hostName" value="localhost" />
  <property name="port" value="1414" />
  <property name="queueManager" value="QM_SANDBOX" />
  <property name="transportType" value="1" />
  <property name="channel" value="SSL_CHANNEL" />
  <property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jms-destination-sandbox" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
<constructor-arg value="SANDBOX_Q" />
    <property name="baseQueueManagerName">
       <value>QM_SANDBOX</value>
    </property>
    <property name="baseQueueName">
       <value>SANDBOX_Q</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**2b**. Create certs, keystores (kdbs), exchange certs etc. There are many ways to do this. But be mindful that you will need to stash passwords, the key label for the queue manager must be ‘ibmwebspheremq*qmgr*’ – all in lower case, no spaces, (without quotes), the key label must be like ‘ibmwebspheremq*userid*’ – all in lower case, no spaces, (without quotes) where userid is the userid that runs tomcat. If you need more details on exactly how I did it using self signed certs, let me know.

**2c**. Now you have to get the JVM that tomcat runs, to read your keystores. There are many ways but here's how I did it:
Create a setenv.bat file in the tomcat bin folder, with the following contents (debugging SSL is optional)

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\path-to-keystore\key.jks" "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=topsecret" "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\path-to-keystore\key.jks" "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=topsecret" "-Djavax.net.debug=ssl" "-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false"
```

**2d**. Start tomcat using the following command:

```
catalina.bat run > ..\logs\tomcat.log 2>&1
```

To stop, just press ctrl+c (on windows). Whichever way you do it, make sure that setenv.bat is used during start up. Or use JAVA_OPTS to set the keystore properties.

**2e**. Verify that the using the SSL channel works.

**Step 3**: Get a JNDI connection working with non-SSL, JNDI
There are many was to set up JNDI on tomcat. Here's how I did it: Within the web application create a file META-INF/Context.xml with the following contents:

```
<Resource
   name="jms/qcf_sandbox"
   auth="Container"
   type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
   factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
   description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
   HOST="localhost"
   PORT="1414"
   CHAN="NON_SSL_CHANNEL"
   TRAN="1"
   QMGR="QM_SANDBOX"/>
<Resource
   name="jms/SandboxQ"
   auth="Container"
   type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
   factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
   description="JMS Queue"
   QU="SANDBOX_Q"/>
```

Now in your spring config, instead of the direct configurations, all you have to do is:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mq-jms-cf-sandbox" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jms/qcf_sandbox" resource-ref="false" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jms-destination-sandbox" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jms/SandboxQ" resource-ref="false" />
```

Note that for brevity, I just didn't use resource references. In case you do, there a few additional steps which are straight forward.

**Step 4**: Now the final step is to use an SSL channel and JNDI. Assuming you have done step 2, this is easy. Modify the META-INF/Context.xml with the following contents:

```
<Resource
   name="jms/qcf_sandbox"
   auth="Container"
   type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
   factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
   description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
   HOST="localhost"
   PORT="1414"
   CHAN="SSL_CHANNEL"
   TRAN="1"
   QMGR="QM_SANDBOX"
   SCPHS="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"/>
<Resource
   name="jms/SandboxQ"
   auth="Container"
   type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
   factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
   description="JMS Queue"
   QU="SANDBOX_Q"/>
```

Note the line with SCPHS="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384". If you need to set other such parameters, see the "Short Form" column in this link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111800_.htm%23jm10910_?lang=en

**Hopefully all this works for you. Good luck!**

Once this configuration works, sending messages is pretty straight forward. But this is how you can listen for a message on a queue using Spring JMS
Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

**Step 1**: Use Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer and configure your beans in an xml file like so (spring-beans.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"      
    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

   <!-- this is the Message Driven POJO (MDP) -->
   <bean id="messageListener" class="jmsexample.ExampleListener" />

   <!-- and this is the message listener container -->
   <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
       <property name="connectionFactory" ref="mq-jms-cf-sandbox"/>
       <property name="destination" ref="jms-destination-sandbox"/>
       <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**Step 2**: Add this to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/spring-beans.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

<listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Step 3**: Write a Message Listener class like so:

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class ExampleListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
            }
            catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, instead of step 3, if you are using spring integration, you can do something like so:

```
<int:channel id="jms-inbound"/>
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="jms-inbound-adapter" container="jmsContainer" channel="jms-inbound" 
        extract-payload="true" acknowledge="transacted" 
        message-converter="messagingMessageConverter" />

<beans:bean id="messagingMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: in detail explanation +1.

Comment: Where you are configuring Step1? name of the file, is it in spring-beans.xml or some other file and how it will read it.

Comment: It's the XML file where you configure your spring beans (could be broken down into multiple files too). Just make sure it is picked up in mentioning that in your web.xml (if it can't be picked up by default based on naming conventions)

Comment: @code4kix . I am just trying to migrate to WAS 8.5 from WAS 7and remove all EJB's and MDB . I have successfully done with EJB's to Spring4 Inject and ComponentContext , now I am stuck with one MDB that I have in code. I was using ActiveSpec to read from WAS.Can you help me how can migrate this in WAS 8.5?

Comment: My suggestion is to completely do away MDBs and active spec. On server, all you need is the qm connection factory and q connection factories. On the application, go with just message driven POJOs (instead of MDBs). I am sure there are examples if you search. If you really can't find any, ask another question in stackoverflow maybe. I will try to get to it if no one else can.

Comment: Hi @code4kix! 3 years later, this is still going to help me. Can you please share a sample source code of this project?

Comment: Wow, ok. I am going to have to work a little to remove sensitive info, and upload a minimal working example. It might take some time. Meanwhile, any specific issue that you are stuck with, that I can help you with?

Comment: Sure code4kix. Thanks a lot. Here is my detailed question, if you wish to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536714/ibm-websphere-mq-ejb-and-mdb-migration-for-tomcat-deployment

Comment: Hi @code4kix. Got that? I am still struggling with this :(

Comment: @Mike, Your question is too generic. You will need to try all the steps I mentioned above one at a time, verify results and post specific questions if you get stuck somewhere.